# What is the proper way of wrapping an Int (not a general type) in another type if type safety is the only motive?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-safety, newtype

I was using a `Map String (Int, Int)` where the two `Int`s were used as the numerator and denominator to form a `Rational` to be passed to [`fromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.6/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#v:fromList).

Then I realized that in a point in my code I had used those two `Int`s the other way around (as denominator and numerator, i.e. swapped). It took some time to find out what was wrong, so afterwards I thought that maybe I should use two dedicated types, so I wrote

```
newtype MyNum = MyNum Int
newtype MyDen = MyDen Int
```

but then I had to add a few instances for everything else to work (given the uses I make of those `Int`s, I had to add `deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)`), and also to add some two functions to unwrap the `Int`s from within the two types so that I could actually apply things like `(+1)` to those wrapped `Int`s.

But this means that code starts looking a bit ugly, with things like `(MyNum . (+1) . unwrapMyNum)`, whereas something like `(+1) <$>` would be much preferrable.

But that means that `MyNum` should be a `Functor`; but it can't because it's a hard type, not a type constructor.

But I don't want to make it a type constructor because I don't want to wrap anything in it other than a `Int`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `newtype` looks like the right thing to use here. Maybe you need `MonoFunctor`. In some cases "safe coercions" can also help reducing the unwrapping/rewrapping. E.g. `coerce ((+1) Int)` should be equivalent to `MyNum . (+1) . unwrapMyNum`. Of course, when you turn on this automatic (re)wrapping you risk mixing numerators and denominators...

Comment: If you're always keeping the two values next to each other then you could use `Ratio Int`.

Comment: Instead of unwrapping values in-line, you can define a top-level `incr` function to make the code that uses it less noisy.

Comment: If your `Int`s are there to form a `Rational`, is there a reason you can't just use `Rational`?

Comment: @DanielWagner, yes, the two `Int`s represent "failed attempts" and "total attempts", so they are initially both 0, but a 0 denominator is not allowed.

Comment: At least regarding the "no zero denominator" issue, it might be better to use `Map String (Maybe (Int, Int))`, and use `Nothing` to signify "no attempts yet". When a `Just t` value is added to the map, you can enforce the `fst t < snd t` and `snd t /= 0` constraints at that time.

Comment: If you want to be able to map `Int -> Int` functions over your type but it can't be a functor, you always have the option of just defining your own mapping function instead of `fmap`. It's **exactly** the same thing you would write if you were defining `fmap` to put in a `Functor` instance. In fact it's simpler to do that because you don't have to wrap the simple function definition in `instance Functor ??? where`. Though if you want to use the same name for mapping functions over multiple types, you have the option of defining your own typeclass too; in fact that's all `MonoFunctor` is.

Comment: If you're counting failures and attempts, it most likely makes sense to keep those numbers separate and not part of a `Rational`. For example, if there have been 2 failures out of 4 attempts representing that as a `Rational` will be normalised to `1 % 2`, and then trying to add one failed attempt would get you to `2 % 3` instead of the correct 3 fails out of 5 total. Really, what you have is not "a numerator and a denominator", so `MyNum` and `MyDen` are not much better than a tuple. Something like `data Attempts = Attempts { failed :: Int, total :: Int }` is the direction I would be going.

Comment: @Ben, yeah, that's mentioned in the accepted answer too. I ended up storing the denominator and the ratio, i.e. the total attempts and the failure rate, which is still 2 dofs like the initial `(Int, Int)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the actual problem has nothing to do with your concrete question. Just **don't use tuples**, use a suitable type that expresses what both integers represent together. In this case the obvious choice would be to use [`Ratio Int`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html), with the caveat that it does not store arbitrary pairs but properly normalises the fractions (which is generally a good thing). If that's not appropriate for you, just write your own `Ratio` type.

That said, there are also many things you can do to make a newtype wrapper around a single type more convenient:

- Derived instances. It seems like you still used numerical operations on the wrapped type. That's easy to enable via the [`DerivingStrategies`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_strategies.html) extension:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}

  newtype MyNum = MyNum Int
   deriving stock (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
   deriving newtype (Num, Enum, Real, Integral)
  ```

  and now `MyNum` is basically a fully featured clone of `Int`, you can directly write expressions such as `negate (n + 9)` for `n :: MyNum`, no need for wrapping and unwrapping. (But the compiler still baulks when you pass a `MyNum` to something that expects a `MyDen`.)
- Mono-functor. If you rather want to emphasize `MyNum` being *a container for an `Int`*, and not *a different kind of number type of its own right*, then there's the [`MonoFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.3/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor) class. You can instantiate

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

  newtype MyNum = MyNum Int

  type instance Element MyNum = Int

  instance MonoFunctor MyNum where
    omap f (MyNum i) = MyNum (f i)
  ```

  and then write e.g. `omap (+1) n`, which is like `(+1)<$>n` but doesn't require the container to support anything but `Int`. Check out also the other classes of the package.
- General wrapping / unwrapping helpers. There are alternatives for explicitly operating on newtype- or other contained data that work also when special classes are not suitable, and can be more convenient than a traditional pair of accessor and constructor. Among them are [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.11.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:coerce) and [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) (more specifically `Iso`s).

Comment: What is the `type instance Element MyNum = Int` line doing? Is it a concise way for doing multiple things at the same type, like defining the type `MyNum`, making it instance of `Element`... ? I haven't really understood what [`Element`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.3/docs/src/Data.MonoTraversable.html#Element) is.

Comment: @Enlico it's not doing multiple things, only one: it specifies that the `MyNum` container contains elements of type `Int`.

Comment: I assume `data MyNum = MyNum Int` too _specifies that the `MyNum` container contains elements of type `Int`_, so where's the difference? That's what I was trying to ask with my previous comment.

Comment: @Enlico not really, `data MyNum = MyNum Int` doesn't say that `MyNum` is a container, just some data type which happens to have an `Int` as a field. You could have `data MyTuple = MyTuple Int Bool`, and then you could declare either `type instance Element MyTuple = Int` or `type instance Element MyTuple = Bool`, or even something completely different (though that would make for a weird `omap` operation).

Comment: You say _You could have `data MyTuple = MyTuple Int Bool`, and then you could declare either `type instance ...`_; but in your snippet you only have `type instance ...`, not a `data` before (nor after) that.

Comment: No no, the data / newtype declaration is of course still needed, I just omitted that from the snippet.

Comment: Do you know why if I put a `foo.cabal` file with `cabal-version: 3.0` beside a file with content equal to your first snippet I get errors telling me to also add `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}` (which indeed fixes the error)? From [`DerivingStrategies`'s doc](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_strategies.html) I understand that the pragma you suggested should be enough, but why it isn't if I specify `cabal-version: 3.0`?

Comment: `cabal-version` has nothing to do with what language extensions are enabled for GHC. But, I also thought `DerivingStrategies` alone would have been enough. Never mind, there's no harm done enabling also `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` explicitly.

Comment: FYI, [I asked](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4899#issuecomment-1949909935). Probably it's just me being dumb :D